# write int from Java client to c server over socket

Tags: java, c, sockets, dataoutputstream

I thought it might be byte ordering but it doesn't look like it.
I am not sure what else it could be.

## Java client on linux

```
private static final int CODE = 0;
Socket socket = new Socket("10.10.10.10", 50505);
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
output.writeInt(CODE);
```

## c server also on linux

```
int sd = createSocket();
int code = -1;
int bytesRead = 0;
int result;

while (bytesRead < sizeof(int))
{
    result = read(sd, &code + bytesRead, sizeof(int) - bytesRead);
    bytesRead += result;
}

int ntolCode = ntohl(code); //test for byte order issue

printf("\n%i\n%i\n%i\n", code, ntolCode, bytesRead);
```

Which prints out:

```
-256
16777215
4
```

Not sure what else to try.

## Solution

This solution is not intuitive in the least for me, but thanks for the down votes anyway!

## Java side

```
Socket socket = new Socket("10.10.10.10", 50505);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
int x = 123456;
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
byte[] b = buff.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(x).array();
out.write(b);
```

## C side

```
int sd = createSocket();

char buff[4];
int bytesRead = 0;
int result;
while (bytesRead < 4){
    result = read(sd, buff + bytesRead, sizeof(buff) - bytesRead);
    if (result < 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    bytesRead += result;
}

int answer = (buff[3] << 24 | buff[2] << 16 | buff[1] << 8 | buff[0]);
```

I am still interested in a simpler solution if anyone has anything, preferably using BufferedWriter if that is possible.

Comment: Just tried, same output

Comment: Your code does not check for `result = -1` that can be returned by `read()`.

Comment: Yea I figured I'd leave out some error checking for this question.

Comment: You can't use a `BufferedWriter` for binary data, and the code in your edit doesn't advance the buffer pointer at all.

Comment: oh man, i am glad you caught that.

Comment: cute how the massive amounts of SO trolls always downvote everything - especially the things they dont understand :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
&code + bytesRead
```

This will increment the address of `code` in steps of 4 (`sizeof code`), not 1. You need a byte array, or some typecasting.

Comment: Good observation, but only an issue if `read()` doesn't read all 4 bytes on first call, which seems unlikely. I do however agree that reading to a byte array first is better.

Comment: It frequently reads less than 4 bytes in one read call for what ever reason. Thanks, I will give that a try.

Answer (score -3):

You forgot to design and implement a protocol! You wrote one piece of code that sends data in one format and another piece of code that receives data in an entirely different format. Decide on a format, document that format, then write code that sends in that format, then write code the receives in that format.

Do not skip the documentation step. That is the most important one. Document precisely what bytes will be used to communicate the information.

Comment: Why do you think they use "entirely different formats"?

Comment: He is sending a four byte integer in network byte order. You can't claim that isn't a protocol.

Comment: @EJP However he's sending, he's sending it somehow. But if he hasn't documented it, there's no way to say whether that's how he's supposed to be sending it or not. Happening to do something some particular way is not a protocol. A protocol is a specification for how things *should* happen.